# select columns in df from variables in another df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 pandas dataframes, where one lists column names I want to select in the other one when I run it through a loop.

For example:

**df1**:

| selected column 1 | selected column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | C |
| B | C |

**df2**

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| value | value | value | value |
| value | value | value | value |

**I want: (first run):**

| A | C |
| --- | --- |
| value | value |
| value | value |

**(second run)**

| B | C |
| --- | --- |
| value | value |
| value | value |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use iterrows (generally frowned upon when you're working with DataFrames) you can create the DataFrames using comprehension like so:

```
records = [
    {
        'A': 'A1', 'B': 'B1', 'C': 'C1', 'D': 'D1'
    },
    {
        'A': 'A2', 'B': 'B2', 'C': 'C2', 'D': 'D2'
    }
]

selectors = [
    {'C1': 'A', 'C2': 'C'},
    {'C1': 'B', 'C2': 'C'}
]

data_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(records)
sel_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(selectors)

#.T transposes the dataframe and gives us the rowindexes to use in iloc
dfs = [pd.DataFrame(data=data_df, columns=x) for x in [sel_df.iloc[s] for s in sel_df.T]] 

for df in dfs: 
    print(df)
```

Comment: Seems to work, but I cannot seem run it through my loop, as I need to use `.iloc`. 
Can I in any way convert `dfs` into a dataframe?

_ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(247, 446, 2)_

Comment: dfs is just a list of dataframes - you can do a loop like for df in dfs, I've updated the answer to show that.

Comment: Wow! you're a genius. I'm glad I still have some hair left on my hair after the frustration this problem has caused. Thanks for your help.
Hope you have a nice weekend!

Comment: @geaa - I have to admit, that took some time to work through - it was an interesting challenge and I learned something from it!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([["A", "C"], ["B", "C"]],
                    columns=["selected_columns_1", "selected_columns_2"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([["value", "value", "value", "value"],
                    ["value", "value", "value", "value"]], columns=["A", "B", "C", "D"])

for index, row in df1.iterrows():
  print(df2[[row["selected_columns_1"], row["selected_columns_2"]]])
```